# Maximum cycle length in 3n+1 conjecture

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to submit my code at http://www.programming-challenges.com but I only get just wrong answer. I've tried the big input numbers like 1000000 to test and my code returns the answer. if anybody can help I'd be really grateful. Here's my code anyway:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int max_cycle(unsigned int i, unsigned int j);
unsigned int cycle_size(unsigned int m);
void swap(unsigned int *m, unsigned int *n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   unsigned int a, b;
   int scan;

   scan = scanf("%u %u", &a, &b);
   printf("%u %u %u", a, b, max_cycle(a, b));
   while (scan> 0) {
       if((scan = scanf("%u %u", &a, &b)) > 0) {
           printf("\n%u %u %u", a, b, max_cycle(a, b));
       }
   }

   return 0;
}

unsigned int max_cycle(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
    unsigned int length = 0;
    unsigned int max = 0;

    if(x > y) {
        swap(&x, &y);
    }

    x++;
    while(x < y) {
        length = cycle_size(x);

        if(length > max) {
            max = length;
        }

        x++;
    }

    return max;
}

unsigned int cycle_size(unsigned int x) {
    unsigned int cntr = 1;

    while(x != 1) {
        if(x % 2 == 0) {
            x = x/2;
        } else {
            x = 3*x+1;
        }

        cntr++;
    }

    return cntr;    
}

void swap(unsigned int *x, unsigned int *y) {
    unsigned int term = 0;

    term = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = term;
}
```

Comment: which problem are you trying? can you give the link to that question instead of the homepage of the website?

Comment: Hi if you have the book, the first problem of the book (3n+1) :), if not i try to write it down here.

Comment: Here' s the problem: Consider the following algorithm to generate a sequence of numbers. Start with an integer n. If n is even, divide by 2. If n is odd, multiply by 3 and add 1. Repeat this process with the new value of n, terminating when n= 1. For example, the following sequence of numbers will be generated for n= 22:
22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
It is conjectured(but not yet proven) that this algorithm will terminate at n= 1 for every integer n. Still, the conjecture holds

Comment: for all integers up to at least 1,000,000. For an input n, the cycle-length of n is the number of numbers generated up to and including the 1. In the example above, the cycle length of 22 is 16. Given any two numbers i and j, you are to determine the maximum cycle length over all numbers between i and j, including both endpoints.

Comment: @MartinR, i used unsigned int and the maximum number is 1000000.

Comment: But the intermediate numbers can get bigger, try with long long

Comment: Btw, this is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture. As an example, if you start with 27 then the numbers in the sequence climb to 9232 before descending to 1

Comment: I don't think your program includes the endpoints

Comment: @MartinR, yes in case of number is odd. thanks.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz, what do you mean?

Comment: If x is 1 and y is 2, then I think your program will return 0

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz, yes you're right. but the problem says numbers between i and j. i don't think any input like (1, 2) (2, 3) (4, 5)... is used.

Comment: If the input is `1 2` or `1000 1001`, then 0 is not a correct answer.

Comment: @n.m., what should i return for this input?

Comment: You do not include the endpoints in your calculations though the problem specifically asks to include both endpoints and any number in between.

Comment: @n.m., yes but sample input is like this (suppose - is newline):
1 10 -
100 200 -
201 210 -
900 1000 -

Comment: How do you derive from the sample input what the output should be like? If the input is `1000 1001`, then your answer should be equal to `max(length(Collatz(1000)),length(Collatz(1001)))`, which is not `0`.

Comment: @n.m., sorry, in main function in the while loop i read from standard input and write to standard output. standard form of input is what i said above. and output should be like input but including the maximum number at the tail of for example 1 10 20 (20 is maximum for input 1 10).

Comment: What are you trying to prove? Your program is not judged by feeding it input you know. It is judged by feeding it input you don't know. Your task is to make your program correct for all inputs, not for the one input you are given as a sample.

Comment: @n.m., i just mentioned the input for the format of it not saying my program works fine with this input. i asked you what should i return for the inputs like 1 2 - 3 4 ... that don't have any integer number between them and see where we are now!!!!

Comment: Do you understand what "including both endpoints" means? It does not mean you should print the endpoints along with the answer. It means that the endpoints should be included in the list of numbers you process.

Comment: @n.m., Thank you, i got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a fatal mistake in your code. You completely ignore integer overflow. You don't have to search long until you find an x starting a sequence that doesn' fit into 32 bits. Since an x with a sequence that doesn't fit into 32 bits is quite likely to create a long cycle, you are likely to miss numbers with maximal cycle length.

64 bit will go a bit further, but not that much.

Comment: Yes, thanks for answer. i should use long long for that. i'll try that and post the result.

Comment: No, 64 bits are more than enough for starting numbers up to 1000000. 32 bits would be enough for starting numbers of up to 100000.

Comment: The [problem statement](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=29&page=show_problem&problem=36) says: "_You can assume that no operation overflows a 32-bit integer._"

Answer (score 0):

The output of your program lacks the final `\n`. Replace

```
   int scan;

   scan = scanf("%u %u", &a, &b);
   printf("%u %u %u", a, b, max_cycle(a, b));
   while (scan> 0) {
       if((scan = scanf("%u %u", &a, &b)) > 0) {
           printf("\n%u %u %u", a, b, max_cycle(a, b));
       }
   }
```

with

```
    while (scanf("%u%u", &a, &b) == 2)
        printf("%u %u %u\n", a, b, max_cycle(a, b));
```

to remedy that.